# UISearchbar with UIStoryboard: segues and custom cells do not work correctly

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uistoryboard

I am using storyboards and want to implement a UISearchbar for my UITableView. The UISearchbarController generates a new UITableView and I use the following strategy:

```
if (tableView == self.tableView)
   //Populate table view with normal data
else
   //Populate table view with search data
```

The first problem is to deal with custom cells. I have to instantiate them in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Normally you would do that from a nib file. How do I do this from with storyboards? dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil.

The second problem concerns the segue from the table view to the detail view. The segue is initiated in the normal table view, but not in the search table view. Since Storyboards hides everything I have no idea how to assign segues to cells of the search table view.

Could anyone help, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did:

1) I initialized the custom cells in initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:, then implemented the layout in layoutSubviews. So I still have no idea how to load the cells from the storyboards.

2) I pushed the view on the navigation stack instead of using the storyboard segues.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the first problem i solved it by changing the ViewController type from UITableViewController to UIViewController  , then adding table view inside it and add IBOutlet for the table view

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *_tableView;
```

use the outlet to dequeue the table cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell=[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:productMasterCellIdentifier];
    // .. modify your cell
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work well; I kept the `UITableViewController` and just used: `self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:...`.

Comment: Using the [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier...] as suggested by @penfold works well if both the search and main table view point to the same destination view controller. But if the destination view controller is different (even if this is not the common case) then you cannot do that as the segue will not work properly for the search bar. I tested it with my body...

Answer (score 1):

About the second problem: don't link the segue from the cell, but from the viewcontroller. You will need to make two segues in your storyboard with different names. Then manually invoke the segue when the row is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromSearchResults" sender:self];
    }
    else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromAll" sender:self];
    }
}  

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fromSearchResults"]) {
        ..........
        ..........
    }
    else {
        ..........
        ..........
    }
}
```